# How to Parse XML File in PHP

Tags: php, xml

The XML file is [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/cs02/Sample_AlmostEverything_1.2_strict.xlf).
How can I get the source content in this XML file?

Comment: My god that xml is fugly.  Why would you want to get anything from it anyway?

Comment: This file is simply. the ms office 2007 docx file xml ooxml is more fugly.

Comment: DOM is good ->  
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($extrato);
$root = $document->getElementsByTagName("OFX")->item(0);
$stmttrn = $root->getElementsByTagName("STMTTRN");

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually there are four relatively simple ways to read an XML file:

- [`DOM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) which uses the DOM API (and therefore has to load the whole document into memory)
- [`SimpleXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which provides a very simple and elegant way to parse XML documents (but lacks a lot of document manipulation methods), it also loads the whole document into memory
- [`XMLReader`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) is a stream-based XML pull parser. It's usage is not as intuitive as the usage of both other options above, but it can be a life-saver when you have to parse large documents (as it does not need to load the whole document into memory and operates on the XML *stream*). The nice thing is that it allows you to inter-operate with the `DOM` via [`XMLReader::expand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.expand.php).
- [`XML Parser`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) is a very low-level component which allows you to create SAX parsers, which means that you define handler functions which will be called when reading the XML file; essentially they have the same benefits as the `XMLReader` (operating on streams)

My personal favorites are:

- `SimpleXML` when parsing relatively small XML files without the need to modifiy them
- `XMLReader` when parsing large XML files

Comment: DOM is the good one ->   
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($extrato);
$outer = $document->getElementsByTagName("your_outer_tag")->item(0);
$inner = $outer->getElementsByTagName("your_inner_tag");

Answer (score 4):

PHP already includes [XML parsers](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) in the core or as extensions (i recommend [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php)).

Try to use it and then ask us if you have any specific problem.