# Import data from specific XML tag

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

I have a XML document that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<citizen> 
  <military-skills> 
    <military-skill> 
      <level>Marksman</level> 
      <points>1620.735</points> 
      <name>Strength</name> 
    </military-skill> 
  </military-skills> 
</citizen>
```

I want to get the value from the tag "points" using PHP SimpleXML.
In another place, I read I could use "$xml->children()->points;" but it ain't working.

If anyone wonders, [this](http://api.erepublik.com/v2/feeds/citizen_by_name/xml/jacce) is the XML document I want to import.

Comment: You need an XML parser. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706042/how-to-parse-xml-file-in-php) is a good overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite simply with [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/SimpleXML):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('file.xml', 0, true);
$points = $xml->{'military-skills'}->{'military-skill'}->points;
// You can then convert $points to double or float
```